# Is there any evidence that genes which are associated with physically adjacent structures are located near each other within the genome?

Tags: genetics

I am not sure if there are individual genes for, say, fingers and if so, would such genes be near the genes that affect hand growth? If not "near" in the Euclidean sense, could there be a different metric where genes for associated structures could be considered near?

Comment: There aren’t genes for fingers, and the answer to the question of whether genes for associated functions are physically associated in the genome depends on the organism. You need to research the genetics of limb development before asking this sort of specific question.

Comment: @David: can you suggest links or search terms? I of course did try to search but got only general results. If there is an organism which had this property, can you give me an example? I am not merely interested in limb development but general rules for how the genome is laid out.

Comment: I shouldn’t answer in comments, but if you were hoping there were rules — in anything other than bacteria — I’m afraid you will be disappointed. Try searching for operons and gene clusters.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hox_gene#Colinearity

Comment: @canadianer — You really ought to answer rather than comment, as the example you give would appear to be the exception rather than the rule, which the poor computer scientist (for I imagine that is what the poster is) will get the wrong impression.

Comment: @David: pretty good guess except I am a *comfortable* (by no means wealthy) computer scientist.

Comment: @releseabe — Apologies for the "poor", but both on this list and in life I have repeatedly encountered numerical scientists interested in finding problems in biology to apply their skills to. Among the problems that arise are 1. Biology (even the molecular variety) doesn't genearlly follow clean rules, 2. The low-hanging fruit has already been picked, 3. Although biology is intellectually stupid (speaking as an ex-chemist) you need to learn some to understand the problems.(Others on the list will hate me for saying this.)